# QTableWidget Drag/Drop rows does not change their location when accessing by index

Tags: pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a QTableWidget, that allows moving of rows by dragging and dropping.

The initial table looks as follows:

[image]

If clicking on the button,  it prints all the values as they are in the table.

Now after dragging row 2 to the the position of row 4, the output does not change.

[image]

Output:

```
Item in row 0, col 0 has value Name
Item in row 0, col 1 has value City
Item in row 1, col 0 has value Aloysius
Item in row 1, col 1 has value Indore
Item in row 2, col 0 has value Alan
Item in row 2, col 1 has value Bhopal
Item in row 3, col 0 has value Arnavi
Item in row 3, col 1 has value Mandsaur
```

The expected output:

```
Item in row 0, col 0 has value Name
Item in row 0, col 1 has value City
Item in row 1, col 0 has value Alan
Item in row 1, col 1 has value Bhopal
Item in row 2, col 0 has value Arnavi
Item in row 2, col 1 has value Mandsaur
Item in row 3, col 0 has value Aloysius
Item in row 3, col 1 has value Indore
```

Why is this the case and how can I print all the rows by their actual, new location?

Example:

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5.QtCore import *#QPointF, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import *#QPainterPath, QPolygonF, QBrush,QPen,QFont,QColor, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *#QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsSimpleTextIt


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTableWidget'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

        # Row count
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)

        # Column count
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)

        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Name"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("City"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Aloysius"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Indore"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Alan"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Bhopal"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Arnavi"))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Mandsaur"))

        # Table will fit the screen horizontally
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.button = QPushButton("Print all the values in the table, in the right order!")

        def get_all_the_values_in_the_table():
            #row_counter = 0
            print("  ")
            print("  ")
            for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):

                for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                    print("Item in row "+str(row)+", col "+str(col)+" has value "+str(self.tableWidget.item(row,col).text()))

        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: get_all_the_values_in_the_table())
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Show window
        self.show()






if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Edit 1:

Thought that perhaps the item has the same location in the table, but a different index. Yet trying to solve this by getting the index does not work neither. Where's the trick?

```
print("Item in row "+str(row_)+", col "+str(col_)+" has value "+str(self.tableWidget.itemFromIndex(self.tableWidget.indexFromItem(self.tableWidget.item(row_,col_))).text()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving header sections does *not* change the model layout, only the *visual* representation: if you move the first header to another place, the first *row* in the model will still be the previous one. In fact, if you closely look at the vertical header, the labels (which by default indicate the *model index*) are moved also.

If you want to print the model based on the header layout, you need to call [`logicalIndex()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#logicalIndex):

```
        def get_all_the_values_in_the_table():
            print()
            print()
            header = self.tableWidget.verticalHeader()
            for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                # get the logical index based on the visual index
                row = header.logicalIndex(i)
                for col in range(self.tableWidget.columnCount()):
                    print("Item in row {}, col {} has value {}".format(
                        i, col, self.tableWidget.item(row,col).text()))

        self.button.clicked.connect(get_all_the_values_in_the_table)
```

Note that:

- using lambda to call a method or function that doesn't require specific arguments is unnecessary, just connect to the function as done above;
- [`width()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop) and [`height()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) are existing members of all QWidgets, you should not overwrite them;
- it's not necessary to call `setDragEnabled` and `setDragDropMode` to make header sections movable, as `setSectionsMovable` will suffice;

Comment: you're the best! Thank you!